# Como faço para listar todas as propriedades de um objeto?

Tags: python

Eu queria pegar somente as propriedades de um objeto, e passar o valor de cada uma dessas propriedades como argumento para uma funcao.

Comment: Somente propriedades? Ou atributos e métodos também? Pode explicar melhor o que pretende fazer?

Comment: o melhor aí seria coloca rum exmpo do que vocẽ quer: ponha uma classe pequena com o tipo de dados que voce quer, como voce cria  uma instancia dessa classe, e a chamada que gostaria de fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode iterar sobre todos os componentes da classe do seu objeto e buscar por aqueles que são do tipo `property`. Para pegar todos os componentes, podemos utilizar a função `dir`, que retornará tanto atributos de classe, como atributos de instância, métodos e propriedades. Para buscar apenas as propriedades, basta filtrarmos esta lista pelo tipo. Vale lembrar que a lista de componentes deve ser elaborada a partir da classe do objeto e não do objeto em si, pois caso contrário o retorno da função `type` da propriedade daria o tipo do valor da propriedade e não da propriedade em si.

Como exemplo, imaginamos a seguinte classe:

```
class Foo:

    atributo_de_classe = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.atributo_de_instancia = 2

    @property
    def propriedade(self):
        return 3

    def metodo(self):
        return 4
```

Defini tanto atributo de classe, quanto de instância, método e a propriedade, cada uma com o próprio nome para facilitar a identificação. Se é desejado obter apenas as propriedades, o único valor retornado deverá ser `propriedade`.

Definiremos, assim, a função que pegará o nome de todas as propriedades de um objeto:

```
def get_properties_names(obj):
     classname = obj.__class__
     components = dir(classname)
     properties = filter(lambda attr: type(getattr(classname, attr)) is property, components)
     return properties
```

Assim, se criarmos uma instância da classe supracitada e chamarmos esta para função para a mesma, teremos:

```
foo = Foo()
properties = get_properties_names(foo)
print(properties)  # ['propriedade']
```

Retornando apenas o nome das propriedades da classe. Para obter o valor de cada propriedade, podemos utilizar a função `getattr` com o objeto:

```
foo = Foo()
properties = [getattr(foo, property) for property in get_properties_names(foo)]
print(properties)  # [3]
```

Retornando a lista de valores das propriedades do objeto. Assim, você pode utilizar a desconstrução de lista para passar, por exemplo, por parâmetro a uma função:

```
another_function(*properties)
```